# Android Notification and NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, notifications, compatibility, nosuchmethoderror

I build a notification:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(
                            getApplicationContext())
                            .setTicker(
                                    getApplicationContext().getString(
                                            R.string.my_string))
                            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym)
                            .setContentTitle(
                                    getApplicationContext().getString(
                                            R.string.my_string_two))
                            .setContentText(a.getB())
                            .setSound(
                                    RingtoneManager
                                            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                            .setVibrate(new long[] { 10001000 })
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,
                                                    new Intent()
                                                            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                                            .setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE)
                                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK),
                                                    0));
                    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nm.notify("interstitial_tag", 1, builder.build());
```

With android 4.0 i've found an error: NoSuchMethodError.
How can i solve it? Do i use Notification.Compact?
Thank you.

Comment: Please post full exception, including the exception message that says which method was not found.

Comment: Also, get rid of `getApplicationContext()` and use `this` in all occurrences in this code snippet. Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know *why* you are using `getApplicationContext()`. See http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: The log said that the error is in the line of the PendingIntent. Then, i use the getApplicationContext() because this is called in method run and there i can't use "this".

Comment: What API level is your minimum?  You may need .getNotification() instead of .build()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
public static void sendNotification(Context context, String info){
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
//title notifications
notifyBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
//small icon
notifyBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
//set contentText
notifyBuilder.setContentText(info);
notifyBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 200, 100, 500});       notifyBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
//setAutoCancel
notifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

getNotificationManager(context).notify(0, notifyBuilder.build());
}

public final static NotificationManager getNotificationManager(Context context) {
return (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
}
```

And when you used a new Intent(), please insert a destination class

```
Intent wrapperIntent = new Intent(context, SenderBroadcast.class);
wrapperIntent.putExtra("KEY_UID", uid);
wrapperIntent.setData(Uri.parse("senderbroadcast://"+uid));
wrapperIntent.setAction("REQUESTCODE_SENDERBROADCAST");
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, RequestCode.REQUESTCODE_SENDERBROADCAST, wrapperIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```